Where is this address sanitizer command supposed to go?
In MSVC if I do this with address sanitizer turned on I get a runtime exception:
#include <vector>

    int main()
    {
    
    
        std::vector<int> my_vector;
        my_vector.reserve(20);
        my_vector.assign({ 1, 1, 1 });
        int* p = my_vector.data();
        std::cout << p[3];
    /*ERROR: AddressSanitizer: container-overflow on address 0x11d4a44ebf1c at pc 0x7ff6a882ae53 bp 0x0020d85cf720 sp 0x0020d85cf728
    READ of size 4 at 0x11d4a44ebf1c thread T0*/
    }

HINT: if you don't care about these errors you may set ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_container_overflow=0.
If you suspect a false positive see also: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerContainerOverflow.

I took me a while to figure out that this command is supposed to go in Environment variables under the "Debugging" menu. What I don't get is that ASAN isn't just a debug thing. For example I can run it in Release mode with the sanitizer on, why is it that ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_container_overflow=0 must be passed as a debugging environment variable? At first I thought it was supposed to be passed to the compiler options or as a preprocessor definition or something.
Is there a way to set this in CMake? I've tried:
set(ENV{ASAN_OPTIONS} "detect_container_overflow=0")

My CMake:
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "GNU")
    message("Using GCC compiler")
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
    message("Using Clang compiler")
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
    message("Using MSVC compiler")
    add_compile_options(
        /MP # MULTIPROCESSOR COMPILE 
        /Oi # ENABLE COMPILER INTRINSICS
        /utf-8
        $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/fsanitize=address>
        $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:/fsanitize=fuzzer> 
        
    ) 
    set(ENV{ASAN_OPTIONS} "detect_container_overflow=0") # SET THIS BECAUSE SHADERC THROWS A FALSE POSITIVE ERROR BECAUSE THE LIBRARY WASN'T COMPILED WITH SANITIZER ON 

else ()
    message("Unknown compiler: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}")
endif ()

This has no effect on the ASAN flags, so it's not going into the right place.

You are aware that your assign only assigns 3 elements, so p[3] is still outside the valid range?

@ChristianStieber I intentionally indexed outside the range so I could get the error, and then testing what I did to turn it off the error.

Environment variables are inherited to child processes -- if you set one in cmake, the compiler will see it because the compiler is run from the cmake process.
However, you are not running your .exe from inside cmake, so whatever environment variable you set in the cmakedoes not affect your .exe.
If you run your .exe from a cmd window, you should be able to do something like set ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_container_overflow=0 before running your program. Other than that, you can set it in system properties -- but that will affect all programs you're running (although I suppose not a lot of these have ASAN built in).
